# Wait for subscription to finish before continuing loop

Tags: angular, typescript, loops, subscription

I have an Angular application that gets data from an API and gets one of its parameters from a looped array. At the moment, it pushes the data I need in a random order since it continuously loops without waiting for the subscription to end at pushes whoever finishes first.

```
    let parameterArray = ["a", "b", "c"]
    let finalData = []
    
    parameterArray.forEach(parameter => {
       let tmpValue = /* Apply logic for parameter data transformation */
       forkJoin(this.apiService.getApiData(tmpValue)).subscribe(response => {
          let transformedData = /* Data logic */
          finalData.push(transformedData);
       })
    })
```

This causes the API to be called multiple times which isn't ideal, but all I need at the moment is a way to loop through the parameterArray and be able to push the transformed data in the correct order. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you using forkJoin there? Does `getApiData` return an array of Observables?

Comment: I would use `map` instead of `forEach` and return the observable. Then I use `forkJoin` on the result of that and subscribe to it.

Comment: Yes it does return an array. I'll try using map and see if that works thank you

Comment: When you say it returns an array, do you mean it returns `Observable<something[]>` or `Observable<something>[]`? Those two things mean different things.

Comment: It returns an array of Observables so Observable<something>[]

Comment: Ok! Then my initial comments stand. If you want further help I can create an answer.

Answer (score 0):

a ForkJoin is used when we has an array of observables generally this observables are create trnasform an array using "map"

```
forkJoin(
   this.parameterArray.map(x=>{
     tmpValue=..what ever with x..
     return this.apiService.getApiData(tmpValue)
   }  //the result is an array of observables
).subscribe(res:any[])=>{
   in res[0] you has the response to this.apiService.getApiData(tmpvalue)
        calculate with "a",
   in res[1] you has the response to this.apiService.getApiData(tmpvalue)
        calculate with "b",
   in res[2] you has the response to this.apiService.getApiData(tmpvalue)
        calculate with "c",

})
```

Comment: It seems like`getApiData()` returns an array of Observables, so you still need forkJoin inside the map. Either that, or use flatMap instead, in which case you'll have to handle the subscription differently.